# ionic 4 tab ionViewWillEnter fires before the device readyReady event

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, events, ionic4

I have the initializeApp code in my app.components.ts constructor which looks like below:

app.components.ts

```
constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,

    ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

initializeApp() {

    this.platform.ready().then(async() => {

      this.statusBar.styleDefault();

       //set device info
       this.core.deviceId = this.device.uuid
       console.log("Device id is::" + this.core.deviceId)
}
```

I have tabs layout with tab1 showing as default. This tab has ionViewWillEnter method making use of above device id. The problem is that tab1.ts is getting invoked before deviceReady is fired.

What is the solution to defer firing in tab1.ts until device ready is fired and initialized?

tab1.ts

```
  ionViewWillEnter(){
    console.log("got in with id:" + this.core.getUserKey())
    this.core.refreshData()
  }
```

Comment: what do you want to show to user meanwhile?

Comment: also what is “core”? can you call refreshData from app.component?

Comment: core is just a service class to hold app wide data and some utility methods. i can call refreshData in app.component. but just failing to understand why tab1.ts is not waiting for app.component deviceready to finish?

Comment: ah i see, so “platform readiness” is not a blocker for your html/css/js code when it comes to cordova. It is a mere hook to signify that other non-web parts of cordova have initialized and ready (plugins basically). So this is by design.

Answer (score 1):

You can use observable for that to access deviceId whenever it is set in app.component.

core.service.ts

```
public deviceId: Subject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);

broadcastDeviceId(deviceId:string) {
   this.deviceId.next(deviceId);
}
getDeviceId(): Observable<any> {
   return this.deviceId.asObservable();
}
```

app.component.ts

```
 initializeApp() {
     this.platform.ready().then(async() => {
        //set device info
        this.core.broadcastDeviceId(this.device.uuid)
     })
 }
```

tab1.ts

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
    console.log("got in with id:" + this.core.getUserKey())
    this.core.getDeviceId().subscribe(deviceId:string)=>{
     console.log(deviecId)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

**ngOnInit** in your component for initialization

```
ngOnInit(){
  console.log("got in with id:" + this.core.getUserKey())
  this.core.refreshData()
 }
```

[Ionic Page Life Cycle](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle)